# Lost time and weather app

Tags: applications

Lost my weather app and absolutely want that version back. Have scrolled through 500! versions in play store and others but can't find. Is there a history of what I had and deleted so that I might reinstall exact version? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a list of all apps that you have installed from Google Play. 
Go to Google Play app → Apps & Games → My apps & games → ALL.

*Note, that you will not find there the apps that were pre-installed on your smartphone by the manufacture and that are not available in the Google Play store.*